# Return 2 variables in Javascript - Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to find an item and the index of this item inside array and store this in 2 separate variables. Quite new to programming but struggling to solve the problem. I tried destructing but it is not working

```
    const [{item:item,index:index}] = notification.pendingQueue.forEach((item,index)=>
         {
             if(item.taskId.toString()  === req.params.taskId)
             return [{item, index}];
         })
```

Tried this as well

```
const data = notification.pendingQueue.forEach((item,index)=>
         {
             if(item.taskId.toString()  === req.params.taskId)
             return ({'item': item,  'index': index})
         }) 
         

         console.log("item", data.item );
```

I'm getting this error

undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

------ Edit -------------

As suggested by the community member, I tried .map method but now the issue is I get results like this if the 2nd element matches the condition.

```
[undefined, {item,index}, undefined]
```

so doing object destructing is becoming a problem. I want the final array to contain just the matching object and remove all undefined values.

```
const [{ item, index }] = notification.pendingQueue.map((item,index)=>
         {
             if(item.taskId.toString()  === req.params.taskId)
             return { item, index };
         }) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.forEach` do not return any value. You should use map instead :

```js
const [{ item, index }] = notification.pendingQueue.map((item,index)=>
         {
             if(item.taskId.toString()  === req.params.taskId)
             return { item, index };
         }) ;
```

Note that `item` and `index` may be undefined if your condition is not fulfilled.

To remove undefined you can chain map result with `Array.filter` :

```js
const [{ item, index }] = notification.pendingQueue.map((item,index)=>
         {
             if(item.taskId.toString()  === req.params.taskId)
             return { item, index };
         }).filter(elem => elem !== undefined) ;
```

Comment: As you said. If there are 3 elements in Array, I'm getting [undefined, element, undefined] as result. I just want the first element that matches this condition and avoid all other undefined values. How can it be achieved?

Comment: Added more context in the question again by added an edit section

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple values from a function by wrapping them in an iterable. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on destructuring assignment.

```js
function coordinates (country = null) {
   if (!country) return [-1, -1];
   // ...
   let lat = "19.9823";
   let lon = "0.9039";
   return [lat, lon];
}

const [a, b] = coordinates("London, UK");
```

Or

```js
function coordinates (country = null) {
   if (!country) return {-1, -1};
   // ...
   let lat = "19.9823";
   let lon = "0.9039";
   return {lat, lon};
}
const {lat, lon} = coordinates("Tokyo, JP");
```